# What actions are considered to be idempotent in RESTfull scenarios?

Tags: http, post, get, http-post, httprequest

Consider I want to develop a RESTfull WebApi for a Book Store. I'll have an Api to get a book info like: `books/1`.

I want to create a log whenever someone gets a book info. So, later I can produce a report of which book is seen more through the Api.

As in this scenario I'm getting some information it seems more appropriate to use GET. But as it changes some data, it could be a SET request.

**Question:** Does some changes like `Logging` effect on idempotent behavior of an action?

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern is that a GET of a resource should not modify the resource in such a way that a subsequent GET of the same resource gets a different result.

Side-effects such as logging are not part of the data model, so are not generally considered to be related to whether the action is idempotent or not.